# catch a non existant subdomain with nginx or apache 2?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, redirect

Is it possible to detect a non existant subdomain inside a "catch all" setup?

- user1.domain.ltd works
- user2.domain.ltd works
- nonexistant.domain.ltd does not work would like to redirect this to default.domain.ltd

are there any ways to do this?

**I need a serverside way to detect if a subdomain is non existant to show a default one **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# existing domains
server {
        server_name
                    s1.example.com
                    s2.example.com
        ;
}

# non-existing domains
server {
        server_name ~^.*$;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ s1.example.com$1; 
}
```

Comment: Your nginx config is ugly. Please read: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Answer (score 3):

```
server {
    server_name user1.example.com;
    [...]
}

[...]

server {
    server_name default.example.com;
    [...]
}

server {
    server_name *.example.com;
    return http://default.example.com$request_uri; 
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Good one with `return`, thanks. Didn't know this syntax.

Comment: The *. has been deprecated for a while now.